# X-Men : Days of Future Past - Kitty Role

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

I was thinking Kitty aka Shadow Cat, her only power was that she can move through objects or let objects pass through her or go through walls and ceilings. In the new X-Men movie *Days of Future Past*, i see her sending wolverine's mind to past. Is that her ability which she had orginally or it was just an ability that they have created for the movie ?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer to this question has already been posted [How can Kitty Pryde achieve time travel with her phasing abilities?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58740/how-can-kitty-pryde-achieve-time-travel-with-her-phasing-abilities)

Comment: The technical term for a kitty roll is “[purrito](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-QQc_cYtYS3E/TwNiN7qDOOI/AAAAAAAAADU/SC5URUnrFpo/s230/FreeChipotlePurrito.png)”.